# process termination doesn't affect waitpid()

Tags: c, linux, operating-system, system-calls

I need to simulate the following bash commands using C under Linux (with fork, exec, kill, signal, wait, waitpid, dup2, open, sleep, pipe etc).

```
[0] echo 'tail-f $1' > /tmp/rtail
[1]/tmp/rtail ~/.bash_history >> /tmp/1.txt &
PID of process [1] should be saved.
[2] Expect termination of the command started on step [1]. After termination print on the screen: "Program 1 terminated."
```

So far I have this code:

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>  
#include <sys/wait.h> 

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    pid_t pID = fork();
    if (pID == 0) // child
    {
        int file = open("/tmp/rtail", O_CREAT | O_WRONLY);

        //Now we redirect standard output to the file using dup2
        dup2(file, 1);

        puts("tail -f $1");
        close(file);
        system("chmod 777 /tmp/rtail");
        exit(0);
    } else if (pID < 0) // failed to fork
    {
        printf("Failed to fork");
        exit(1);
        // Throw exception
    } else // parent
    {
        pid_t pID2 = fork();
        if (pID2 == 0) {
            char tmp1[20];
            sprintf(tmp1, "echo %i > /tmp/pidprog1", getpid());
            system(tmp1);


            int file = open("/tmp/1.txt", O_APPEND | O_WRONLY);

            //Now we redirect standard output to the file using dup2
            dup2(file, 1);
            FILE* proc = popen("sh /tmp/rtail ~/.bash_history", "r");
            char tmp[20];
            while (fgets(tmp, 40, proc) != NULL) {
                printf(tmp);
            }
            fclose(proc);

            exit(0);
        }
        else if (pID2 < 0) // failed to fork
        {
            printf("Failed to fork");
            exit(1);
            // Throw exception
        } else {
            FILE* fl = fopen("/tmp/pidprog1", "r");
            char buff[10];
            fgets(buff, 10, fl);
            int pidc = atoi(buff);
            fclose(fl);
            int status;
            waitpid(pidc, &status, 0);
            printf("Program 1 terminated\n");
        }
    }

    // Code executed by both parent and child.  

    return 0;
}
```

The problem is that when I manually kill the process using PID saved into /tmp/pidprog1, parent process doesn't stop waiting and doesn't print "Program 1 terminated" line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parent is very likely reading a garbage value into pidc.  You are doing nothing to ensure that the grandchild has actually written the pid before the parent tries to read it.  You need to use wait to ensure that valid pids are in the file. (Or, just keep track of the pids from the return value of fork.)

You are not doing enough error checking: what happens if any open fails?  (eg, when you try
to open /tmp/1.txt for appending but it doesn't already exist?)

Why are you using fgets to read 40 characters into a buffer of size 20?

Why are you dup'ing and using fputs instead of just writing to the fd?

Why are you printing error messages to stdout instead of stderr ( use perror ).

Comment: And how to wait for a grandchild if the whole purpose of writing to a file is to save the grandchild's PID?

Comment: Well, most of inaccuracies are due to the fact of the draft stage of the code. I'm using dup instead of writing to the file directly because I think the task says explicitly I should prefer this method.

Comment: @bvk256 Use wait to wait until the child is finished.  But why are you getting the pid from a file?  It is returned by fork().  To pass the pid of the grand child to the parent is a little more work, usually done through a pipe rather than the file system.  You need some kind of synchronization. Either use wait, or open a pipe, or use some other form of IPC.

Comment: Does your homework specify that the pid should be saved in a file, or does it just say "PID ... should be saved".  It is not at all necessary to save it, since it is returned by wait, and it is very unusual to save it in a file.  Store it in a variable.  Call wait and use the return value, and ignore the stored value.

Comment: There is also second part of the assignment, second program should be created and it should kill the first one after some time in the meanwhile using saved PID. So writing to a file is necessary for the second program to know the PID of the first.

Comment: Thanks, using your suggestions I was able to solve most of the problems, and realized how stupid the question was after reading the man for wait() again.